# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi/dns stops working

Tags: wireless, 16.04, dns

My Ubuntu 16.04's WiFi used to work fine, but it has been displaying rather peculiar behavior ever since I came to Japan.

I haven't had the chance to try different networks, but here is what happens when I try to use my apartment's network:

Everything works fine for about a minute, after that I can only use google to search stuff, but when I try to enter a website I get

> This site can’t be reached
>
> www.google.co.jp’s server DNS address could not be found.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration

And after roughly 8-9 minutes, I can't even search stuff on google. It starts giving me the same error.

At this point I tried pinging 8.8.8.8 via `ping -c5 8.8.8.8`, and it worked.

But `ping -c5 google.com` gives me `ping: unknown host google.com` . Although I can successfully ping `google.com` during the first sweet minute when everything works.

My /etc/resolv.conf looks like this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN 
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search flets-east.jp iptvf.jp
```

Despite the notice, when I edit this file by hand (changing the nameserver line to `nameserver 8.8.8.8`), the internet works just fine but my changes are gone when I reboot the computer.

Where do yo think the problem is? Could it be some WiFi setting? Or some wireless adapter driver issue?

By the way, I can browse without any problem with my phone or when I boot into Windows 10.